# How to search for a word but replace characters in the line above in gvim

Tags: search, vim, replace

In the code below, I want to replace/remove the `,` from the line above `.VSS(VSS)`.

It is at multiple places in the file. I have basic knowledge of gvim and I could not figure out how to just search and then pipe it with replace.

```
ANTENNABWP7THVT ANTENNABWP7THVT_spr_gate156 (
    **.I(LTIELO_NET), 
    .VSS(VSS),** 
    .VDD(VDD));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching each line that contains `.VSS(VSS)` and doing something with it can be done with [`:global`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal). You then want to address the line above it; that's a [`:help :range`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange): `.-1` (or short `-1`). And removal of a (all with the `/g` flag) comma can be done with plain [`:substitute`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute). Taken together:

```
:global/\.VSS(VSS)/-1substitute/,//
```